# Displaying and navigating a tree in discord

Tags: discord, discord.js

This is more of a logical than a programming question, but how would I go about displaying a tree in a discord bot?

I have tried to sort of break down the tree into six parts and have the user be able to click on each of those parts, but it just seems a bit counterintuitive.

I have a user progressing through a skill tree, and I want a way for the user to display their progress through it by rendering a tree and maybe having some type of navigation through it. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: In case you are talking about a `Tree` as a data structure, usually you do things with trees using recursion, as in `renderNode() { render(this); foreach (child in children) child.renderNode();}}`

Comment: @monomo Thank you for the answer, I was more so asking what would an intuitive way of displaying it be. How could I show the tree (yes, the data structure) in an intuitive way since discord is a pretty limited platform.